# VBScript returns an error of "Name redefined"

Tags: vbscript

I have an alert box, and if I'm currently on the test Database, I want the alert box to have different text when compared to live database.

So I declared a variable called `isTestDb` and set it to `True`, but I keep getting this annoying error:

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0411'

Name redefined

myfiles/conn_open.asp, line 12

Dim isTestDb
----^
```

Here is my simple code which sits inside an include at a much higher level than where I'm doing my conditional check, I'm assuming that isn't a problem.

```
Dim isTestDb

isTestDb = True


-- Much Later in another file somehwere

If isTestDb Then
    Response.Write("<h1>It is set to True</h1>")
    Response.End
Else
    Response.Write("<h1>It is set to False</h1>")
    Response.End
End If
```

I have checked all my working directory and I'm certain that variable is not set somewhere else by the same name, I even tried different names for the variable and got the exact same error.

Comment: What does 'reversed word' mean in this context? I have updated to show where variable is set. Thanks David.

Comment: Can't see a problem with the code you've posted, there must be more to it than just these bits... Whats on line 12 of "conn_open.asp"?

Comment: The only thing that is different is where the check is being done (different file through includes), otherwise, that is my exact code :/

Comment: If you get a "name redifined" error, then you *definitely* have redefined a name. Maybe you have a Function/Sub with that name elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why, but when I removed the `Dim isTestDb` line, it all works as expected now!! :/

Comment: VB dialects are case insensitive, maybe you missed the original declaration because of that?

Comment: It's because the file you include conn_open.asp also has a Dim in it

Comment: @Tomalak that can't be it, because I used variables named after cartoon characters, and it was still giving the error.

@LasseEdsvik why would that matter if the `Dim` in the other files were named differently?

Comment: On a general note I strongly recommend writing no VB code without `Option Explicit`. Other than that it's hard to pin down without seeing your entire code, but the error is definitely on your end, not on the VBS end.

Comment: If you removed the `Dim isTestDb` line and it is now working fine, changes are that you are overwriting an earlier used variable with global scope. While it seems everything works as expected, strange and difficult-to-debug errors are luring in the dark. Change your variable name (do a case insensitive search so you are not forgetting one in your script!), use option explicit and try to limit the usage of global variables to a minimum.

Comment: @DavidCandy no I was Visual Studio 2012, does that suffer from the same problem?

Answer (score 9):

In my case this was due to the fact that I had referenced the same file twice in my .asp file using:

```
<!--#include file="myFile.asp">
```

And the referenced file had the declaration in it hence the second declaration conflicted with the first

Answer (score 5):

This is happenning because the variable, `isTestDb` has already been defined in another page.

Answer (score 2):

it can also be because you are including file you **already** including in other include file.

For example:
File a.asp is including x.asp.
And in your main file you including both:

```
<!--#include file="a.asp">
<!--#include file="x.asp">
```