# Error: Name redefined

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make a vbs script, that when run between 7 and 15 minutes types a character. This is my first time using vbs. When I run the file, I get a error box saying "Error: Name redefined Line 14 char 5" Here is my script

```
Set wshShell = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
do
dim max,min
max=900000
min=420000

Dim RNDM
Randomize
RNDM=((max)*Rnd+min)

wscript.sleep (RNDM)
wshshell.sendkeys "{^}"
wscript.sleep (RNDM)
dim max,min
max=900000
min=420000

Dim RNDM
Randomize
RNDM=((max)*Rnd+min)

wshshell.sendkeys "{%}"
wscript.sleep (RNDM)
dim max,min
max=900000
min=420000

Dim RNDM
Randomize
RNDM=((max)*Rnd+min)

wshshell.sendkeys "{*}"
dim max,min
max=900000
min=420000

Dim RNDM
Randomize
RNDM=((max)*Rnd+min)

wscript.sleep (RNDM)
wshshell.sendkeys "{@}"
dim max,min
max=900000
min=420000

Dim RNDM
Randomize
RNDM=((max)*Rnd+min)

wscript.sleep (RNDM)
wshshell.sendkeys "{/}"
dim max,min
max=900000
min=420000

Dim RNDM
Randomize
RNDM=((max)*Rnd+min)

wscript.sleep (RNDM)
loop
```

Comment: Unless you are using `option explicit` you are not forced to Dim at all. But I strongly advise to use it to discover undeclared/initialized vars. If the dimensions of a Dim'ed var no longer match you can use Redim.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript Error Name redefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952455/vbscript-error-name-redefined)

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring variables multiple times.

See documentation on the `Dim` command here: http://ss64.com/vb/dim.html

> Explicitly declare a new variable or array variable.

You only need to declare a variable once. You can then reuse it as many times as you like.  Also, you are setting the same values over and over again.